# How can I achieve this in php string to bbbvvvvzzxxc => 3v4v2z2xc

Tags: php

How can I achieve php char count with php :

input : bbbvvvvzzxxc

output : 3b4v2z2xc

I try this code :

```
$str = "aabbbccaaaac";
$arr1 = str_split($str);
$count=1;
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$char) {
    if($key==0){
        $pre=$char;   
    }
    if($pre==$char){
        $count++;  
    } else{
        $count=1;
        $pre=$char;
    }
echo $pre.'---'.$char.'__';
    if($pre != $char){
        echo $char. $count   ; 
    } else {
     // echo $char;  
    }
         
}
```

but not working :

its simple to set count of character

Comment: are you want with this code to compress the string, then you want to decompressing it ?, or just an exercise script ?

Comment: Why is it `3v` instead of `3b`?

Comment: This is called "run length encoding". Try googling it.

Comment: "Not working" is a bit broad - what have you tried to debug the problem? This looks like a pretty good exercise to learn some test-driven development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "aabbbccaaaac";
$arr1 = str_split($str);
$count=0;
$pre = '';
$result = ''; // our result string
foreach($arr1 as $char){
  
   if($char == $pre){
      $count++;
   }else{
      
      if($count > 0){ // To check whether it was the first iteration
         $result .= $count.$pre;
      }
      $count = 1;
      $pre = $char;
   }
 
}

$result .= $count.$pre; // For last iteration
echo $result;
```